# Компиляция команды JZ в NASM

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Я попробовал скомпилировать следующий 16 битный код с помощью NASM для процессора i8086:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0]
[CPU 8086]

cmp al, 0
je label

times 1000 db 0

label:
```

И получил такой бинарник:

```
00000000  3C00              cmp al,0x0
00000002  0F84E803          jz near 0x3ee
00000006  0000              add [bx+si],al
...
000003EC  0000              add [bx+si],al
```

Инструкция JZ в данном случае транслируется в `0F84E803`, но в документации к i8086 я не нашел никаких упоминаний инструкций, опкодом которых может быть `0F`. Выходит, что приведенный выше код не должен компилироваться под i8086, или я не прав?

Comment: попробуй поменять адрес jz near 0x3ee на другой, например jz near 0xFFF, что получится?

Comment: @ВладимирМалахов выдает ошибку: No instruction for this CPU level. Только почему он в первом случае такой ошибки не выдает?

Comment: упс, я просмотрел. это же скомпилированный код уже был. я хотел сказать, поменяй адрес перехода на другую метку

Comment: Пробовал две разные версии nasm, в обоих случаях генерируется пара `jne` / `jmp` в обход ограничений 8086, а yasm и tasm компилировать отказываются. Либо вы что-то путаете, либо версия nasm с ошибкой.

Comment: @extrn Два дня назад установил последнюю версию с оф. сайта

Comment: Только что проверил на Ubuntu Linux и там он как и положено ставит связку jnz/jmp вместо jz. А на windows последняя версия неправильно это компилирует.

Comment: Опкод не `0F`, а `0F84`. Под 8086 возможно не будет работать.